# How to set layout to inner components in adobe flex applicaion?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, adobe

I have a Adobe Flex based desktop application. Which has fixed width and height. Now I want to provide maximize and resize features to the app. But the inner components are not being adjusted according to the resized width and height.

How to set proper layout or how to provide configuration to make the inner components align with new dimensions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use constraints (top, bottom, left, right) and percentage based layouts (width="50%" rather than width="200") for all of the child components in your app... then when you resize the parent container, all of the children will adjust based on the constraints.

[Here is an Adobe document explaining how to use constraints properly](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7df9.html)